# Implementing a Variable in a Label Name in VB?

Tags: vb.net, loops, label

I currently have a huge IF statement and want to minimize it as much as possible.

I have a datagrid that i am populating from a SQL query and then from this datagrid i am passing the values into seperate labels.

I am able to create a For Each Loop in which i cycle through the variables looking until a counter reaches 7. However the problem arises when i need to incremente the Label name values by one. Each time, so essentially i need to add a counter variable into the Label name.

The code that i need to minimize is:

```
result73 = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result74 = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString
result75 = DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result76 = DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value.ToString
result77 = DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result78 = DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value.ToString
result79 = DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result80 = DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value.ToString
result81 = DataGridView1.Rows(4).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result82 = DataGridView1.Rows(4).Cells(1).Value.ToString
result83 = DataGridView1.Rows(5).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result84 = DataGridView1.Rows(5).Cells(1).Value.ToString
result85 = DataGridView1.Rows(6).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result86 = DataGridView1.Rows(6).Cells(1).Value.ToString
result87 = DataGridView1.Rows(7).Cells(0).Value.ToString
result88 = DataGridView1.Rows(7).Cells(1).Value.ToString

If result73 = "Monday" Then
    DaySalesLbl1.Text = result74
ElseIf result73 = "Tuesday" Then
    DaySalesLbl2.Text = result74
ElseIf result73 = "Wednesday" Then
    DaySalesLbl3.Text = result74
ElseIf result73 = "Thursday" Then
    DaySalesLbl4.Text = result74
ElseIf result73 = "Friday" Then
    DaySalesLbl5.Text = result74
ElseIf result73 = "Saturday" Then
    DaySalesLbl6.Text = result74
ElseIf result73 = "Sunday" Then
    DaySalesLbl7.Text = result74
End If
```

This If Statement goes on for each variable that is declared above.

The Loop I have created looks something like this:

```
Dim cou As Integer
Dim n As Integer
cou = 0
n = 1
Do Until result74 <> ""
    If result73 = cou Then
        DaySalesLbl +n = result74
    End If
    cou = cou + 1
    n = n + 1
Loop
```

But the section `DaySalesLbl +n = result74` brings an Error because it looks for a generated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as I suspect, this is a WinForm project, then you can access the controls by name using the `Form.Controls` collection, like this:

```
Dim cou As Integer
Dim n As Integer
cou = 0
n = 1
Do Until result74 <> ""
    If result73 = cou Then
        Dim l As Label = CType(Me.Controls("DaySalesLbl" & n), Label)
        l.Text = result74
    End If
    cou = cou + 1
    n = n + 1
Loop
```

The `Controls` collection contains all the controls that are direct children of the form.  You can access them by index (e.g. `Me.Controls(0)`), or by name (e.g. `Me.Controls("DaySalesLbl6")`).  However, the collection stores the list as the base `Control` type, so you have to cast it to a the specific type before accessing the specific properties.  That is why the `CType(..., Label)` is there in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I would write code as follows:

```
For i as Integer = 0 to 7
   Select Case DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString 
    Case "Monday"
       Me.Controls("DaySalesLbl" & i+1).Text = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString 
    Case "Tuesday"
       Me.Controls("DaySalesLbl" & i+2).Text = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString 

   ... etc ...
```

I did this without the IDE, so I hope I didn't mess anything up, but I hope this sets you in the right direction and helps.